# Could not add new key-value pair to existing json array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I am adding one new key value pair to json array which has fetched from MongoDB but its not adding. I am explaining my code below.

```
const CustomerCollection = loadMongoModel(CUSTOMERS_COLLECTION);
let Customer = await CustomerCollection.find({'CustomerMobile' : { $regex : new RegExp(search)}}).limit(limit).skip(skip).sort({ updatedAt : -1 });
resultCount = await CustomerCollection.find({}).count();
            if (Customer.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i< Customer.length; i++) {
                    const CustomerGroupMapCollection = loadMongoModel(CUSTOMERGROUPMAPPING_COLLECTION);
                    const count1 = await CustomerGroupMapCollection.find({GroupCustomerId:Customer[i]['CustomerID']}).count();
                    if (count1 > 0) {
                        Customer[i]['checked']= true;
                    }else {
                        Customer[i]['checked']= false;
                    }
                    resultRecord.push(Customer[i]);
                }
            }
```

Here I want to add `checked=true/false` to each record but its not adding. I need to add this `key-value` pair.

Comment: Do you have that key `checked` as a property in the model?

Comment: That `Custom` variable seems to be an object from the library you are using and not directly a json that why. You might want to either modify your model definition to add that key or convert it to json to manipulate it.

Comment: No, I have add this in result document only I dont need it in model.

Comment: What is `loadMongoModel` doing? Is this trying to read collection from mongoDB and returning collection object?
Also did you put the consoles for `resultRecord.push(Customer[i]);` inside loop and check if it is iterating?

Comment: here `Customer` is keeping all customer record from customer collection. Records are fetching correctly but I need to add one extra key value before going to client page.

Comment: You cannot add fields to collection like this

Comment: Then how it can be done without adding in collections.

Comment: You need to update in mongoDB instead of adding it like this.By using `findAndModify` query of mongoDB. Will that work for you?